# Mysqli last insert id not work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get last query insert id.but my code always return zero.

My Code

```
private function Cnn()
{
    return mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','db');
}
protected function MyCommandInsertId($sql)
{
    if(mysqli_query($this->Cnn(),$sql))
    {
        return mysqli_insert_id($this->Cnn());
    }
    $this->err = mysqli_error($this->Cnn());
    return false;
}

public  function Insert()
{

        $sql = "insert general_info(name,email,password)
        values('".$this->ms($this->name)."','".$this->ms($this->email)."','".md5($this->password)."')";
        //print''.$sql.'';

        $last_insert_id=$this->MyCommandInsertId($sql);

}
```

here return `mysqli_insert_id($this->Cnn());` always return zero

Comment: The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.  [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: column have AUTO_INCREMENT attribute @silverfox

Comment: Check there is an new record inserted in your table or not?

Comment: Insert command is not correct.please check

Comment: You are creating a new database connection every time you call your method `Cnn`.

Comment: CBroe, You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the definition of `mysqli_insert_id`:-

The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the id (generated with AUTO_INCREMENT) used in the **last query**.

It means either column in your table that have `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is not exist.

Or

No insertion of data happen programmatically on your table in the curren program flow. Since no insert query is fired in your code, it returned **Zero**.

**Note:- Just do an insert query first in your code and then check what is the output given by `mysqli_insert_id`. Then you can understand easily what i am trying to say.Thanks**

A working example of my local is here:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
function Cnn()
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','stack');
    return $conn;
}
function MyCommandInsertId($sql)
{
    $conn = Cnn();
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
    {
        $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        return $lastid;
    }else{
        $err = mysqli_error($conn);
        return $err;
    }

}
function Insert()
{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO bom(bom_description,product_id,finish_product,bom_quantity,UOM) values('Table cleaner','','','','')";
        $st_insert_id = MyCommandInsertId($sql);

        echo $st_insert_id;

}
Insert();
?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/9u2iyv (inserted id) and http://prntscr.com/9u2j6i(table view after insertion)

Answer (score 1):

According to 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

There 2 possible problems

1. no previous query on the connection
2. the query did not update an AUTO_INCREMENT value

solutions:

1. Check there is an new record inserted in your table
2. Check that whether your field is AUTO_INCREMENT or not.

---

By CBroe, you are make a new connect.
So, it considers you did not insert the new record.

---

rewrite the function Cnn() and change it into a private variable.

Comment: Yes record inserted and id column have AUTO_INCREMENT attribute

Answer (score -2):

In my case, my sqli was declared outside the current function scope

```
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

What I needed to do was to add `global` in front of my `$conn`

```
function want() {
    ///...... query stuff
    global $conn;
    $conn->insert_id; // Now works
}
```